# Tag synonym request: [mac-os] to [osx]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

The [mac-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) tag has four questions, all relating to OS X (one is even tagged with both).

Following the lead of [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/synonyms), I suggest that the tag (and its synonym [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos)) be merged into [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx).

An alternative would be to use it for questions about Classic (i.e. pre-X) Mac OS, but we already have [mac-os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-classic) for those. Plus such questions are greatly outnumbered by questions about OS X anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that makes sense. Mac OS Classic quesitions are too rare, and the tag's just been used in the wrong way.

I created a synonym [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) ← [mac-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) and [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) ← [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos).

For Classic, we'll use [mac-os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-classic). Thanks for creating the tag wiki.

Comment: That was fast, thanks!