# OS X / macOS tag synonyms should be reversed

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

It's been [a few years](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6393/tag-synonym-request-mac-os-to-osx) since we synonymized [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) to [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx). At the time, we did this to distinguish incorrect uses of the tag from questions related to the old “Classic” Mac OS tagged under [mac-os-classic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-classic).

Now, Apple has stopped calling their Mac operating system “Mac OS X” and “OS X”—it's “macOS” from macOS Sierra onwards. Therefore, we should reverse the synonym direction and point/merge all [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) questions to [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos).

Wikipedia has done the same, [pointing OS X to macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

Note that this will not affect existing questions carrying a tag related to pre-macOS releases (e.g., [osx-yosemite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite)).

Comment: Would it be worth merging the osx tag into the macos tag?  There are 18,000 questions and I really don't know if the tag change is relevant....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging or Linking Tags](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11501/merging-or-linking-tags)

Comment: @Burgi, you're right, but it sounds like a much better idea when an ex-moderator suggests it.  :-)  Since the action has already been completed and answered here, maybe we should just link the other way and make the earlier question a dupe of this one to close the loop.

Comment: *grumble grumble* ;)

Comment: @Burgi Thanks, I hadn't seen that! At the time it was still a rumor, so maybe that's a case for creating a new post.

Comment: @Mokubai A merge seems like the logical next step, but I feel like I'm a little out of touch with what the rules about this (and the impications) are these days.

Comment: I will always call it OSX untill 11.xx.xx comes witch then i'll probably switch then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Done for [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) as master and [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) as synonym

Also pointed [mac-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) at [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) rather than [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx)

Comment: Thanks! It seems I can no longer access the old OS X tag wiki we had. I think we need to copy this to the macOS tag page – it had a nice overview of all the versions and question guidance. Wasn't there a … secret orphan wiki page mod tool?

Comment: Yeah, seems that we had to create a new macOS tag for it to work (oops). Copied gratuitously from the orphaned tag wikis page, and edited it as appropriately.