# Rename [macos-sierra] to [osx-sierra]

Tags: discussion

According to some searching and [this meta post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12014/os-x-macos-tag-synonyms-should-be-reversed), it seems that [macos-*] was changed to [osx-*]. However, it looks like [macos-sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra) didn't make it, or the rule was forgotten. I believe it should be [osx-sierra]. Searching [macos] in [tags](https://superuser.com/tags) points out the problem, compared to searching [osx].

Can we make the name change? There are 166 tagged questions.

Comment: That meta discussion was to move *to* macos-sierra in line with Apple effectively renaming the OSX product line to macOS. The current tag is correct and is current policy.

Comment: @Mokubai Ah interesting, I didn't know that. I guess I should have read a little more closely, huh!